# Canvas - Restrict line in a circle boundary

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

**How can I restrict a line in a circle boundary?**

I want my drawed line to be cut off when it exceeds the max length (100px) but the line keeps restricting inside a rectangle.
I think I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.

[image]

```
var midX = canvas.width/2,
    midY = canvas.height/2,
    x = (mouseCurrent.x - midX),
    y = (mouseCurrent.y - midY),
    maxX = midX+clamp(x,-MAX_LENGTH,MAX_LENGTH),
    maxY = midY+clamp(y,-MAX_LENGTH,MAX_LENGTH);
ctx.moveTo(midX, midY);
ctx.lineTo(maxX, maxY);
```

I've created a fiddle to show my problem:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbAgU/)

Comment: Well it looks as if the current bounds are adjusting to a square of length of the diameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Get the angle from the mouse to the circle centerpoint.
- Use trigonometry to get the point at radius distance at the calculated angle.
- draw a line from the centerpoint to the calculated point on the circumference.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Zje8Y/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    draw(100,100);

    function draw(x,y){
        var cx=150;
        var cy=150;
        var r=50;
        var dx=x-cx;
        var dy=y-cy;
        var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
        var xx=cx+r*Math.cos(angle);
        var yy=cy+r*Math.sin(angle);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
        ctx.lineTo(xx,yy);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(xx,yy,5,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      draw(mouseX,mouseY);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a very elegant and clean solution. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `clamp` function, when you pass it `-MAX_LENGTH` and `MAX_LENGTH` as the min and max boundaries, doesn't take into account anything related to the angle the line is at.

For example, in your picture, the y value would be clamped to `-MAX_LENGTH`, which obviously, from the middle, will extend to the bottom-most point of the circle, and the x value will be clamped to `MAX_LENGTH`, extending as far as the right-most point of the circle.

What you should do is calculate the angle made from the mouse position, and use the sine and cosine of that angle to determine the coordinates.

---

You'll want something like this:

```
var x = (mouseCurrent.x - midX),
    y = (mouseCurrent.y - midY);

var angleInRadians = Math.atan2(x - midX, y - midY);
var realX = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
var realY = Math.sin(angleInRadians);
```

Then, from the `realX` and `realY` values, you should be able to create your line. You might have to tweak this a little bit. I tried to adjust based on the fact that the origin isn't at (0, 0).

Comment: I see know what I'm doing wrong :) Thanks. Care to explain with code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic trigonometry to calculate the angle and you can find the point intersecting with both the line and the circle.

First use tangent of the line to calculate angle. Then use angle value to find x and y coordinates of the point that you are looking for. Here is the code:

```
angle = Math.atan2(mouseCurrent.y - midY, mouseCurrent.x - midX); 
maxY = midY + Math.sin(angle) * MAX_LENGTH;
maxX = midX + Math.cos(angle) * MAX_LENGTH;
```